# Cómo hacer para que una propiedad en C# sea editable solo en esa clase?

Tags: c#, poo

```
 class A
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

}
class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        MyProperty = "100";
    }
}
```

Cómo le hago para que MyProperty tenga que ser inicializada en B, pero por ejemplo si existiera una clase C que heredara de B esta no pudiera inicializar MyProperty, se me ocurrió poner la clase B como sealed, pero no se si esta bien. Solo B puede editar el valor de MyProperty(dentro de la clase) pero si creo una instancia de B no se pueda establecer MyProperty.

Comment: He respondido a la pregunta, pero veo que cuando te preguntas no te molestas en marcar las respuestas aceptadas. Por favor, haz el [tour] para ver como funciona este sitio.

Comment: No estoy seguro de entender el problema, pero creo que lo que quieres es proteger `MyProperty` en una clase C derivada de B, es asi? En ese caso, yo redefiniría la propiedad en `B` usando `new` y definiendola como `private set`. Algo así: `public new string MyProperty { get; private set; }`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo generando una nueva clase A en B:

```
using A;

class B
{
   public B(string myProperty)
   {
       A.MyProperty = myProperty;
   }
}
```

O también puedes hacerlo fuera del constructor:

```
var propiedad = new A{ MyProperty = //Valor };
```

De esta manera tu propiedad A es única en B y puedes usarlo, la primera al iniciar B pasandole un parametro y la segunda puedes meterlo dentro de una función interna de B o como una variable global

Comment: Pero,se puede utilizando herencia? es que acá solo veo una propiedad estática y una instancia directa de A. es decir que B heredando de A inicialice MyProperty pero unicamente dentro de B pueda editar la propiedad, incluso la instancia de un objeto de B que no pueda establecer el valor a MyProperty